# How to get url fragments (anchor parameter) through redirectTo in Angular routing

Tags: angular, url-routing

I am trying to do Angular routing redirect through router tables and wondering is there any simple way to have url fragments through the redirect. I have something like this:

```
{
   path: ':word',
   redirectTo: 'blah/:word',
   pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

When i run this with parameter like localhost:4200/test#fragment Angular redirects it to localhost:4200/blah/test without the fragment. I have managed to bypass this by doing a resolver where I redirect to the right place with fragment, but it feels stupid because then I need to put I dummy component to the router like this:

```
{
   path: ':word',
   resolve: { _: RedirectResolver },
   component: DummyComponent, // We never go here
}
```

If I omit the component, then Angular won't work. Is there any good or native ways to accomplish this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can set "preserveFragment" to true (doc : https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras)

Comment: I am not trying to do it with router.navigate but through router tables redirectTo

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I read too fast, not on my computer right now, does the path and redirect value accept '#fragment' ? Example ':word#fragment' -> 'blah/:word#fragment' I'll try this when I get to my computer

Answer (score 0):

A solution, that facilitates guards:

```
{
    path: '/',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: Component, // Component from '@angular/core' as dummy component because we need something to put here (either component or redirectTo or loadChildren)
    canActivate: [
        (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): UrlTree => {
            return inject(Router).createUrlTree(['redirect'], { fragment: route.fragment });
        },
    ],
},
```